# How can I set adifferent service time for each job / vehicle in JSprit?

Tags: logistics, jsprit

Some employees are faster than others doing the services so the service time is different for each one. Its there any way to apply a multiplier on service time for each vehicle?

Other more exact approach would be to provide a service time / vehicle matrix with the duration calculated for each vehicle, I can pre-calculate this matrix with SVM. Is possible to give this data to JSprit?

**Edit:** I know that its possible to specify a duration for each job.
What I'm asking for is to assign a matrix of different service times for each job depending on the vehicle.

Comment: I removed the OptaPlanner tag as this questions is about JSprit.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not easily possible. However, since it is OS you can tweak it for your own.

If you do not want to go into the details, please open a new feature request in jsprit's issue tracker. There is actually an open pull request on it. This might be also helpful.